# Multer Uploaded Audio File Metadata

Tags: node.js, metadata, multer

I am setting up a file upload route with Multer and it's working fine. However, I'm unable to figure out how to get the uploaded audio file metadata such as album, artist, length, etc. Is it possible to get such metadata with multer? Is there an alternative that provides upload metadata?

Route:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const multer = require('multer');


const uploadDest = 'public/media/';
const allowedMimeTypes = ['audio/wav', 'audio/mp3'];
const filter = function (req, file, cb) {
  if (!allowedMimeTypes.includes(file.mimetype.toLowerCase())) {
    cb(null, false);
  }
  cb(null, true);
};

var upload = multer({
  dest: uploadDest,
  fileFilter: filter,
});

// '/upload'
router.post('/', upload.array('media', 12), function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('file-upload');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: `multer` only handles the upload, to extract metadata from uploaded audio file, you'll need additional library to do so.

Comment: @Neverever Thanks. Do you have a recommendation of such library to narrow down my search?

Comment: No, I'm not an expert in audio related work. Google should give you some recommendations, do try each of them and see which fits better in your project.

Comment: @user5056973 Did you find out good middleware to use?

Comment: @cullanrocks Hey cullan, thank you for reminding me to update this post. I just posted an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using [music-metadata](https://www.npmjs.com/package/music-metadata) to parse the files' metadata after multer has finished uploading them.

Comment: Nice! I'll definitely check that out. I was using ffmetadata but it couldn't pull all the metadata fields I wanted. I'll definitely check out music-metadata. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks... This definitely works, use it without wasting your time.